# Finding Expression Using Truth Table

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, computer-science, computational-mathematics, binary-operations

Below is a truth table I made for this expression: (p → q) ∧ (p ∨ q). My question is, is there a simple, basic operation between two logic variables that have the same exact outcome as the expression I got from this truth table and expression?

[image: Truth Table]

Comment: Note $(p\to q) \land (p\lor q)$ is true if and only if $q$ is true.  So your expression is equvilent to the statement  "$q$".  That's all there is to it.

Comment: If you're wondering why there is such a deduction leading to the same result as your truth-table, you might want to look at [that answer on sematic vs syntactic](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/a/10790/5320), especially paragraph 3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

${ } { } q { } { } { { } } { } { } { } { } $

Comment: Why the downvote.  It *is* the answer.

Comment: That's what I was thinking too, but wouldn't the expression need two variables?

Comment: In this case, the truth value of your statement is independent of $p$.

Comment: " but wouldn't the expression need two variables?"  Why would it need two variables?  If you want a statement with two variables you can always have $q \land (p \lor \lnot p)$. And if you want one with three variables you have $q\land (p\lor\lnot p)\land (w\to w)$.  A statement having two variables doesn't mean it *needs* two variables.  And we can make an equivalent statement with a thousand variables by taking an OR for a thousand tautologies.

Comment: In all seriousness (even more so than before):

$$(p \to q) \land (p \lor q)$$ $$(\neg p \lor q) \land (p \lor q)$$ $$(\neg p \land p) \lor q$$ $$\perp \lor q$$ $$q$$

Deduction rules used: Material Implication, Distribution, Law of noncontradiction, Conjunction with contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the other answers but offer a different perspective.

First of all, re 
"...is there a simple, basic operation between two logic variables"

based on the above, it is unclear whether the answer I am offering is appropriate.

Anyway

$(p \rightarrow q)$ is logically equivalent to $[(\neg p) \vee q].$

Therefore, the statements are converted to 
$[(\neg p) \vee q]$ 
and 
$(p \vee q)$.